# C++ wxWidgets: cross compilation from Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, g++, embedded-linux, cross-compiling, wxwidgets

I have a C++ application that uses WxWidgets. It compiles perfectly with g++ on my computer.

However I need to run the application on a Raspberry Pi 3. Compiling directly on Raspi takes almost an hour.

So I want to do a cross compilation: compile it on my computer and copy the executable to raspberry.

I tried to follow a tutorial, however the generated file is an "x86-64" file:
http://yasriady.blogspot.com/2015/10/how-to-build-wxwidgets-for-raspberry-pi.html

My computer:

- **Ubuntu** 20.04.2 LTS;
- **g++** 9.3.0;
- **wxWidgets** v3.1.5.0;
- **build flags for my computer:** CC_FLAGS=-std=c++17 -w -c -rdynamic -W `wx-config --cxxflags --libs --gl-libs` `geos-config --cflags` -lgeos -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm -lGLEW .

Should I re-install wxWidgets for arm? I'm new to cross-compilation

Thank you so much

---

I already have wxWidgets installed and compiling for x86. Afterwards, I installed wxWidgets for arm-linux following the tutorial.

When I run "`make` for the examples from the `samples` folder, the generated file is for x86.

Maybe "make" is compiling using the x86 compiler, not the newly installed arm compiler.

Comment: @christianpastro, u need to build everything you program uses for raspberry pi. And you can also use `make -jN` to speed up the compilation. N is the number of cores in the machine +1.

Comment: If you want to cross-compile you need to install an appropriate SDK, GTK and its dependencies for raspberry pi then compile and check.

Comment: You can also install raspberry pi vm and do compilation there.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cross-compile for RPi without any problems, double check that you've specified the correct `--host` option and didn't get any errors from configure (if you did, look at `config.log` to see why).